# Why can't RSpec find the Airbrake env keys in a test involving Sidekiq when I specify environment?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sidekiq, airbrake

Here is my setup:

**airbrake.rb**

```
require 'airbrake'

Airbrake.configure do |c|
  c.ignore_environments = [:test, :development]
  c.project_id = ENV['PROJECT_ID']
  c.project_key = ENV['PROJECT_KEY']
end

use Airbrake::Rack::Middleware
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
    FactoryGirl.define do
      to_create { |instance| instance.save }
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    Airbrake.configure(:test) do |c|
      c.project_id = ENV['PROJECT_ID']
      c.project_key = ENV['PROJECT_KEY']
    end
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

**worker_test_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe NotificationWorker do
  it "perform should call Airbrake#notify" do
    anotification_worker = LNotificationWorker.new
    airbrake_notification_worker.perform("some error message"))
    expect(Airbrake).to receive(:notify).with("some error message")
  end
end
```

I call Airbrake#notify in other (non-Sidekiq) tests, and they find the appropriate ENV variables just fine.

Yet if I run the above Sidekiq test with the above setup, I get the following error:

```
Airbrake::Error:
       the 'default' notifier isn't configured
```

But if I change the Airbrake config in spec_helper.rb to:

```
Airbrake.configure do |c|
  c.project_id = ENV['PROJECT_ID']
  c.project_key = ENV['PROJECT_KEY']
end
```

the ENV keys are able to be found in the tests.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `Airbrake.configure(:test)`, it does not mean "configure Airbrake for the `test` `RAILS_ENV`". Rather `:test` creates a non-default [named notifier](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#creating-a-named-notifier). Then you can send specific notifications to that notifier by saying `Airbrake.notify("oops", {time: Time.now}, :test)`. But that is not about development/test/production, it is about categorizing your notifications.

So the problem is that you have configured a notifier named `test`, but you have not yet configured one named `default`, and `default` is what Airbrake wants to use when you don't tell it otherwise. That's why your spec passes when you say simply `Airbrake.configure { ... }`.